# How to cast dictionary key and value all at once in Swift4?

Tags: swift, dictionary, casting

How can I cast dictionary like this at easy way in Swift4?

From this

```
[0:false, 1:false, 2:false]
```

to this

```
 ["0":"false", "1":"false", "2":"false"]
```

I tried this,

```
var dic = [0:false, 1:false, 2:false]
let newdic = dic.map{[String($0) : String($1)]}
```

then it become like this.

```
[["0": "false"], ["1": "true"],["2": "false"]]
```

They are with extra `[ ]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Swift 4 `uniqueKeysWithValues`

```
let newdic = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: dic.map{(String($0), String($1))})
```

Hope it is helpful

Comment: Thanks!! This helps me a lot!!

Comment: @allergyblue If you feel that my answer helped you, you could [accept my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your dictionary like this:

```
var dic = [0:false, 1:false, 2:false]
let newdic = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: dic.map{(String($0), String($1))})
```

newdict: `["0": "false", "1": "false", "2": "false"]`

Comment: Thanks!! This helps me a lot!!